# object str can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python-3.x, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to convert the CSV file to XML and uploading the converted file to Azure Storage container. The code snippet does the necessary operation required, however it fails post the completion of downloading with the error "str can't be used in await expression".

```
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity.aio import DefaultAzureCredential
import os
import io
import shutil

class BlobService(object):
    """
    """

    def __init__(self, blob_name, blob_url, client_id) -> None:
        print(blob_name, blob_url, client_id)
        self.blob_name = blob_name
        self.blob_url = blob_url
        

        try:
            self.credential = DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=client_id, exclude_environment_credential=True, exclude_cli_credential=True, exclude_powershell_credential=True, exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=True, exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True, exclude_interactive_browser_credential=True)
            #self.credential = DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=client_id)
            print("Default cred working")
        except  Exception as e:
            print("Defualt cred error: ", e)
        try:
            self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=blob_url, credential=self.credential)
            print("Blob cred working")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Blobservice error : ", e)
        
        
        pass

    async def get_blob(self, copy_from_container):
        """
        """
        print("Downloading file from container using managed identity")

        async with self.blob_service_client as blob_service_client, self.credential:
            
            blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
                container=copy_from_container, blob=self.blob_name
            )
        
            stream = await blob_client.download_blob()
            print("Download complete using managed identity")
            return_data = io.StringIO((await stream.readall()).decode("utf-8"))

            await blob_client.close()

            return return_data
```

It looks like it has some issue while i'm trying to read the data using stream.readll().

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the values of the input variables (`blob_name`, `blob_url`, `copy_from_container`) you are passing.

Comment: Which line is it that has that error?

Comment: @GauravMantri, blob_name is the file name and blob_url is the storage account url and copy_from_container is the name of the container from which the file should be downloaded

Comment: @blueteeth, i assume the error appears to be in the below line return_data = io.StringIO((await stream.readall()).decode("utf-8"))

Comment: @TalendDeveloper then you've answered your own question. `stream.readall()` is returning a string not an awaitable. Are you sure you want to `await` it?

Comment: @blueteeth removing the await returns an empty string

Comment: @TalendDeveloper presumably that means the stream is empty. That sounds like a different problem.